# Garbage value when passed float values to the function accepting integer parameters

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 int ret = 0;
 ret = func(1.0,2.0);
 printf("\n ret : %d \n",ret);
 return 0;
}
func(int a,int b){
 float m = 5.0;
 float n = 6.0;
 int sum = m + n;
 printf("\n sum : %d \n",sum);
 return a+b;
}
```

**EDITED**

sum : 11

ret : -877505847

why the float value passed to the integer throws a garbage value while the float value added and assigned to an integer inside the function gives the correct value 11 ?

Comment: What is the garbage value you're receiving? It looks like you should be returning 3, but what is being returned?

Comment: Can you provide the "garbage" value?  I'm sure it would help diagnose

Comment: Why would you ignore the warning, especially when a reputable source tells you that it's the source of your problem? That's why you're getting downvoted. At least try the suggestion...

Comment: @Angus I've updated my answer to explain why you're getting the wrong result.  Basically, it comes back to needing to provide a declaration for `func`.

Comment: @Sean Cogan :  Sorry , I missed to fix the warning and i was more concerned about the o/p . After fixing the warning , it works good.

Comment: I wasn't the one who suggested it, it was simonc. Give him the credit.

Comment: Sure. But my doubt isn't clarified yet. Please see my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a declaration for `func` before calling it

```
int func(int a,int b);
int main() {
}
int func(int a,int b) {
    // implementation
}
```

Your code presumably compiled with a warning something like `warning: implicit declaration of function 'func'`.  If you'd fixed this warning, you'd also have fixed the error.

It'd be good practice to have the compiler warn you about as many potential problems as possible.  You may also want to guard against the possibility of missing warnings by treating them as errors.  You can do this by adding `-Wall -Werror` to your build command for gcc or `/W4 /Wx` for MSVC.

Note that the correct value is returned if you pass `int`s into `func`.  At a guess, this may be because the calling code doesn't know that it needs to cast the arguments to `int` and passes `float` instead.  `func` then either reads registers/stack locations that `floats` weren't copied to or receives the bit representations of `float` arguments and treats them as `int`.  Either of these will result in incorrect values of `a`, `b` being received.  You can check this yourself by adding a `printf` inside `func` to note the values of its arguments.

Comment: Wouldn't it not even compile without the prototype?

Comment: @SeanCogan It will compile, but with a warning.  Fixing the warning would have fixed the OP's error

Comment: I guess we've used different compilers, then. I used gcc to compile C when I wrote in C, and unless I'm mistaken it wouldn't compile if I didn't have the prototype for my function.

Comment: It does compile under gcc.  Since it generates a warning, if you normally use `-Werror`, your warning would have been treated as an error

Comment: It will compile with the warning implicit declaration of the function

Comment: It will make the default return type as int. As long as we havent defined the function with any other return type other than int, the program holds good

Comment: Ok, never mind then. It's been quite a while since I've written in C, and I usually wouldn't run my programs if they had warnings anyway.

Comment: @simonac : It works fine after fixing the warning. But my doubt is , When passed func(1,2) , it didnt show any garbage value and gave me the correct answer. when i tried to pass func(1.0,2.0) it gave me the garbage value. why did it work when passed integers as parameters.

Comment: @Angus Does the last paragraph of my answer cover this for you?  Presumably the caller and callee agreed on how to pass `int` arguments so we get lucky and the code works.  If you pass `float`, the caller doesn't know that the args need to be cast as `int` and the callee doesn't know it hasn't been passed `int` arguments.  In this case, the callee goes ahead and interprets the start of a `float` (or an uninitialised part of memory) as an `int`.

Comment: @simonc : I put the printf and got the values of the parameters a and b as 1 and 2.

Comment: With which compiler?  That's not what I get with either gcc or msvc.  Have you remembered to remove any forward declaration of `func` before testing this?

Comment: @simonc : you are right . I forget remove the forward declaration, i made in the program. I checked by removing it and got a garbage value for b.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand, though i made mistakes :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Everyone starts out by making mistakes.  The best thing you could learn from this thread is that fixing all compiler warnings can be a nice quick way of fixing some hard to diagnose bugs :-)

Comment: The reason why func (1, 2) didn't give garbage is that the compiler guessed what the types are - since you passed two ints, it guessed that the parameters are int and was right. When you call func (1.0, 2.0) you pass two doubles, so the compiler guesses the parameters are double, and that guess is wrong.