# Passing float to a function with int argument (that is not declared beforehand)

Tags: c

I have read [Garbage value when passed float values to the function accepting integer parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16962039/6643278) answers. My question goes a bit deeper. I could have also asked there had I more than 50 reputation point. I am adding my code for more clarification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void p2(unsigned int tmp)
{
    printf("From p2: \n");
    printf("tmp = %d ,In hex tmp = %x\n", tmp, tmp);
}

int main()
{
    float fvar = 45.65;

    p1(fvar);
    p2(fvar);
    printf("From main:\n");
    printf("sizeof(int) = %lu, sizeof(float) = %lu\n", sizeof(int),
            sizeof(float));
    unsigned int ui;
    memcpy(&ui, &fvar, sizeof(fvar));
    printf("fvar = %x\n", ui);
    return 0;
}

void p1(unsigned int tmp)
{
    printf("From p1: \n");
    printf("tmp = %d ,In hex tmp = %x\n", tmp, tmp);
}
```

The output is:

```
From p1: 
tmp = 1 ,In hex tmp = 1
From p2: 
tmp = 45 ,In hex tmp = 2d
From main:
sizeof(int) = 4, sizeof(float) = 4
fvar = 4236999a8
```

Passing a `float` value to a function that is declared beforehand (i.e. p2) with `int` arguments gives the correct result. When trying the same with a function that is not declared beforehand (i.e. p1) gives incorrect values.  And I know the reason that compiler won't assume any type or arity of arguments for the function not declared before handed. That's why `float` value does not get typecasted to `int` in the case of p2.

My confusion is, in the case of p2, how exactly does `float` value get copied to local `int` variable tmp.

If it is 'bit by bit copy' than reading those locations should yield something (except 1) in hex at least (if not in integer). But that does not sound the case as output shows. I know that float representation is different.

And how p2 may read registers/stack locations that floats weren't copied to? as simonc suggested in the linked question?

I have included the size of `int` and `float` both and my compiler is gcc if that helps.

Comment: it's Undefined Behavior. Don't try to reason it out. By definition it's not defined what happens.

Comment: If you want to define a function after the caller function **you must** add a prototype before the caller function.  That's all

Comment: To elaborate what @LPs said, without that , your code is not a _valid_ C code, anymore.

Comment: Moreover take a look at [compiler errors](http://ideone.com/ZSj5fI)

Comment: You are trying to call a function that has not been declared, so it's automatically declared as `int p1()`. Even though you later define it as `void p1(unsigned int tmp)`, it has already been declared as `int p1()` (not taking any parameters). I'm pretty sure the compiler is screaming with warnings and errors about that, those errors aren't meant to be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. @Antti Haapala's answer explains it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C programming language is essentially a single-scan language - a compiler doesn't need to reread the code but it can assemble it line by line, retaining information only on how identifiers were declared.

The C89 standard had the concept of implicit declaration. In absence of a declaration, the function `p1` is declared implicitly as `int p1()`; i.e. a function that returns an `int` and takes unspecified arguments that go through default argument promotions. When you call such a function giving it a `float` as an argument, the float argument is promoted to a `double`, as called for by default argument promotions. It would be fine if the function was `int p1(double arg)`; but the expected argument type is `unsigned int`, and the return value is not compatible either (`void` vs `int`). This mismatch will cause the program to have *undefined behaviour* - there is no point in reasoning what is happening then. However, there are many old C programs that would fail to compile, if the compilers wouldn't support the archaic implicit declarations - thus you just need to consider all these warnings as errors.

Notice that if you change the **return value** of `p1` into an **`int`**, you will get less warnings:

```
% gcc implicit.c
implicit.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘p1’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 p1(fvar);
 ^~
```

But the observed behaviour on my compiler would be mostly the same.

Thus the presence of mere **warning: implicit declaration of function ‘x’** is quite likely a **serious error** in newly written code.

Were the function declared before its use, as is case with `p2`, then the compiler knows that it expects an `unsigned long` as the argument, and returns `void`, and therefore it would know to generate correct conversion code from `float` to `unsigned long` for the argument.

---

The C99 and C11 do not allow implicit function declarations in strictly-conforming programs - but they also do not require a conforming compiler to reject them either. C11 says:

> An identifier is a primary expression, provided it has been declared as designating an object (in which case it is an lvalue) or a function (in which case it is a function designator).

and a footnote noting that

> Thus, an undeclared identifier is a violation of the syntax.

However, it doesn't require a compiler to reject them.

Comment: I got it. It's undefined behavior. I like your explanation. And I got a question: Why C standard allows it? Shouldn't this undefined behavior give ERROR in the first place (even without using -Werror)? Or is it useful in any case?

Comment: "However, there are many old C programs that would fail to compile, if the compilers wouldn't support the archaic implicit declarations - thus you just need to consider all these warnings as errors."

Comment: It is just the case that implicit function declarations was how it was done in the 70s :D Read more about implicit function declarations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c). Note that the question has doubly-undefined behaviour because it is redefining the built-in function that too has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This,

```
void p1(unsigned int tmp);
```

would be [implicitly declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182835/1983495) as

```
int p1();
```

by the compiler.

Although the compiler does not throw an error, it should be considered one as you can read in the linked post.

In any event, this is undefined behavior and you can't expect a predictable output.

Comment: it would be declared implictly as `int p1()`

Answer (score 0):

In binary level, `float` and `int` don't look alike at all.

When trying to copy a `float` into a `int`, there's an implicit conversion, that's why when you call a function that takes `int` as argument but you provide a `float` you get the integer part of it, but in the final test you get to see how ugly it really look like. That's no garbage, that's how a `float` looks like in memory if you'd print it in hexadecimal. See [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for details.

The issue with `p1()` however is that you are trying to call a function that has not been declared, so it's automatically declared as `int p1()`. Even though you later define it as `void p1(unsigned int tmp)`, it has already been declared as `int p1()` (not taking any parameters) so it doesn't work (behavior is undefined). I'm pretty sure the compiler is screaming with warnings and errors about that, those errors aren't meant to be ignored.

Notice there's a big difference between declaring and defining a function. It is perfectly legal to define a function later, the way you are doing, but if you want it to work properly it has to be declared before any attempt to use it.

Example:

```
// declare functions
void p1(unsigned int tmp);
void p2(unsigned int tmp);

// use functions
int main()
{
    p1(1);
    p2(1);
}

// define functions
void p1(unsigned int tmp)
{
    // do stuff
}
void p2(unsigned int tmp)
{
    // do stuff
}
```